# Issues with VMWare 2.0.2 installation on CentOS 6.3

Tags: installation, centos6, vmware-server

I have an i7 machine (server) and on which I am running CentOS 6.3.  I am trying to install VMWare 2.0.2.0 and I am having problems in identifying the headers for C Compilers when doing the configuration (when running vmware-config.pl).  I have searched the host using "which gcc" provides no results.  I would like to get some pointers as to how to install all the gcc components (gnome C ) and gcc++ for CentOS 6.3.

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 1):

The product has been end-of-life since 2011. It isn't intended for use on EL6. 
Back in the EL5.x days, it was possible to hack around installation issues, but it seems like you're stuck at an earlier process.

To install gcc, you'll need to `yum install gcc` and `yum install gcc-c++`.